# How to know if the user is logged in (in the GSP)

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

I have `index.gsp` that presents a page. In that page there is a button to register, and a button to log in. Once you have logged in, if the login is ok, the app drives you again to `index.gsp`. I need that, if the user is logged in, these buttons disappear, and instead say "Hello, [username]". I've tried with this code, but it doesn't work (it is never logged in):

In the Controller:

```
def dologin(){

    def user=Usuario.findByUsernameAndPassword(params.username,springSecurityService.encodePassword(params.password) )

    if(user){
        redirect (controller:'usuario', action:'index')
    }else{

        flash.message=message(code:'default.user.not.found', args:[message(code: 'params.username', default:'Usuario'), params.id])
    def userlogged = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
                render view: 'index', model: [user: user]
}

}
```

In index.gsp (is not full, only the piece that matters):

```
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>

<div id="buttons">
    <div id="login"><a href="loginurl">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div id="register"><a href="registerurl">Registrarse</a>
    </div>
</div>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
<sec:ifLoggedIn>

<div id="greet">Hello!</div> 

</sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you're doing your own authentication, rather than going through the spring security authentication process.  The `<sec:ifLoggedIn>` tag relies on spring security handling the authentication.

The usual way this is handled in a spring security app is by posting the login request to `/j_spring_security_check`, which, behind the scenes, gets filtered by a [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html).

Grails and the spring security plugin make this relatively painless by providing a `LoginController` and `auth.gsp` that you can use as a starting point.  Run the `s2-quickstart` script (which also creates User and Role domain objects), or just copy them from the `spring-security-core` templates directory.

Comment: Is there an else tag for `<sec:ifLoggedIn>`?

Comment: @styl3r I don't think there's an else tag. Simply use the negated tag `<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it simply

```
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn> // DO SOMTHING</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
<sec:ifLoggedIn> // DO SOMTHING</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it simply

```
<g:if test="${session.user==null}">
<!-- Display buttons-->
</g:if>
<g:if test=${session.user!=null">
    <div id="greet"> Hello, ${session.user.username}!</div>
</g:if>
```

Easier, i think. But, thank you for your answer, ataylor.